# Elasticsearch error syntax: Found two aggregation type definitions in [bucket]: [composite] and [sum_bucket]

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I use ElasticSearch 6.1 and get an error when I try to use composite and sum_bucket together in my aggregation.

It get me an error:

> Reason: Found two aggregation type definitions in [my_buckets_sale]: [composite] and [sum_monthly_sales]",
> Here is a example of what I want to do :

```
{
...
                "size": 0,
                "aggs" : {
                    "my_buckets_sale" : {
                        composite: {
                        size    : 4,
                                sources : [
                                    {
                                        date : {
                                            date_histogram : {
                                                field    : '@timestamp',
                                                interval : 'day',
                                            },
                                        },
                                    },
                                   },
                                ],
                        }
                        "date_histogram" : {
                            "field" : "date",
                            "interval" : "month"
                        },
                    "aggs": {
                        "sales": {
                            "sum": {
                                "field": "price"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    "sum_monthly_sales": {
                        "sum_bucket": {
                            "buckets_path": "my_buckets_sale>sales" 
                        }
                    }
                 }
               },
            }
```

Does anyone know how to do the sum of all the buckets, with keeping my composite ?

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is keep the composite aggregation as it is while still getting the sum of all the sales in every month?
Structure like this:

```
{
   "size" : 0,
   "aggs" : {
      "my_bucket_sale" : {
           "composite" : {...},
           "aggs" : {
              "sum_of_sales" : {
                  "sum" : {"field" : "price"}
              }
          }
      },
      "my_bucket_months" : {
          "date_histogram" : {"field" : "date", "interval" : "month"},
          "aggs" : {
              "sum_of_monthly_sales" : {
                  "sum" : {"field" : "price"}
              }
          }
      }
   }
}
```

Just create a subaggregation on the date histogram to give you the sum as you required. There is no need to mix this with the composite aggrgation.

THanks.

Comment: Thank for the answer, what I do want is the sum of the result of the agg on the sales buckets (the my_bucket_sale), so if two sales are together in an agg, they will be counted as one!

Comment: Do you want the sum of the sales in each composite bucket? If yes, check my edited answer. Pls mark this answer as correct if it helped you!

Comment: No i don't want the sum of the sales in each composite bucket, I am looking for the sum of all composite bucket !

Comment: Then all you need is a "sum" aggregation, without doing anything else. Pls mark the answer as correct, if it helped you